# How to catch "Sorry, This video cannot be played" error on VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a VideoView and I am streaming videos from a remote server. Most of the times It would play the videos very smoothly. But sometimes, it displays an error message "Sorry, This video cannot be played". I have a hunch that this is more on the supported video formats. However, I don't know which are the supported formats. My question is "How can I catch this error (e.g. Prevent the error message from appearing)"? I am using Android 2.2 on this project. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: hmm yes.But I don't know which "catch" will I use. Is there a code that works like VideoView.isPlayable or something that works like that? Thanks for the response :)

Comment: try-catch doesn't work for this case since this is an asynchronous process. You should try setting an onErrorListener. (from the doc. of onErrorListener: "Interface definition of a callback to be invoked when there has been an error during an asynchronous operation (other errors will throw exceptions at method call time).")

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try using [setOnErrorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnErrorListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener%29): the documentation says *If no listener is specified, or if the listener returned false, VideoView will inform the user of any errors.*, so I'm assuming if you set one and return true it will not show the user error.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I will this first and notify you if it works. Thanks :)

Comment: The Dialog will still pop up in my case. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1810737 I think you figured this out in the meantime, but I guess you must return true in OnError to tell Android that you have treated the error yourself.

Comment: @user1810737 you can check my answer. i have solved it using snippet of code

Answer (score 8):

The code I used for this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    vView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    vSource = "android.resource://com.domain.android/"
            + R.raw.introductionportrait;
    vView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(vSource));

    vView.setOnErrorListener(mOnErrorListener);
    vView.requestFocus();
    vView.start();
}

private OnErrorListener mOnErrorListener = new OnErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // Your code goes here
        return true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

you can add code like below, it will close video view screen if any error occurred.
Also, it will not display default popup of saying video can't play :)

```
 videoview.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
                finish();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer setting listeners like this within onCreate method. Hopefully helps someone out

```
videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener () {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error playing video");
        return true;
    }
});
```