# Trigger VideoView onCompletion event on error

Tags: java, android, listener, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

I'm creating a list of videos which are played within a `VideoView`.

I want to catch the "Sorry, this video can't be played" error and just move on to the next video. The video-switching is handled within a `onCompletionListener`.

I already got the code for an `onErrorListener` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8298717/1331671) but I just can't find how to trigger the "video is complete" event.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to catch errors and then play next video or do you just want the OnCompletionListener to be called? Have you set the .setOnCompletionListener for your media player?

Comment: i want the event to be triggered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same in the onErrorListener as you do in the onCompletionListener
in onCompletion you set the video to the next one (somehow, i dont konw your implementation) then in on error use the same code (refactored into another function most likely).
EG:

```
onError(....)
    if(error = watever error you need)
    functionNextVideo()
```

note the above is pseudo code.

But other than that onCompletionListener will not be triggered unless the video completes as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

As found in the source of the  public interface OnErrorListener:

```
@return True if the method handled the error, false if it didn't.
         * Returning false, or not having an OnErrorListener at all, will
         * cause the OnCompletionListener to be called.
         */
        boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra);
```

so the onCompletionListener will be invoked, if you return false or you dont handle the callback.